# GridView Edit with Button Click?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, gridview

I have a gridview and I would like to be able to put it in edit mode with a button click, and not use the command fields built into the `gridview`. Is this possible? Can someone give me some code or a link to an example?

Comment: is button inside the grid or out side the grid??

Comment: I want it to be outside of the grid...

Comment: ok if the button is outside, and you click on that button then which row should go to edit mode???

Comment: the footer row that I have made template fields with various textboxes and dropdownlists.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the [`GridView.EditIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex.aspx) property (zero-based) to the row you'd like to be in edit mode:

```
GridView1.EditIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
```

This sets the last row of the GridView into edit mode.

Typically this is done while loading the page, but it should also work if done in your button's server-side `Click` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `EditIndex` of that gridview to the rows `row_index` you need to set to edit mode

like if you want 3rd row to be edited when button click set

```
GridView1.EditIndex = 2;
```

if last Row to be edited

```
GridView1.EditIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
```

these are some links which might help you

[Asp.net insert, Edit, update, delete data in gridview](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html)

[Manipulate GridView with Datasource](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html)